# Default selection of combo in grid cell in ExtJS 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic, extjs-grid

I have grid panel where some column cells require to show combo box.

I have different services to load grid and combo data. I have different fields in record to show value in grid cell rows.

I want to display default value in combo from grid row record.

One idea is that first I load and bind store to combo and find the record from grid row cell value, and setValue with combo.

I am not sure It is feasible way to bind store to combo while rendering grid data. Will this impact performance ?

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you getting column configuration which having combo from xml or manually mentioning in code.

Comment: Manually by using widget in column configuration

Comment: The way you mentioned is perfect, only problem I can see is if we need to set different value for different combo then it create problem but If store index is same for all the combo then it is absolutely fine. have a look to this fiddle. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1kai

Comment: Fiddle does not exist.

Comment: We don't need to worry about store index and different value for different combo. I can get different values through onWidgetAttach function in column configuration.

Comment: Can you check fiddle now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128118/discussion-between-udid-and-rishabh-shah).

Comment: My point is that is it feasible to bind store to combo box during grid rendering ? Will it impact on performance of grid, if I have thousands of records ?